Vmware unable to launch windows despite virtualization is enabled
I'm trying to use windows in vmware player, but it keeps closed right after I tried to launch windows VM, here is the log.
$ vmplayer 
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/etc/vmware/hostd/proxy.xml"
Warning: program compiled against libxml 212 using older 209

(vmplayer:54602): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:07.814: removable-device-0: missing action removable-device-0

(vmplayer:54602): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:07.814: removable-device-1: missing action removable-device-1

(vmplayer:54602): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:07.814: removable-device-2: missing action removable-device-2

(vmplayer:54602): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:07.814: removable-device-0-choose-image: missing action removable-device-0-choose-image

(vmplayer:54602): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:07.814: removable-device-0-edit: missing action removable-device-0-edit

(vmplayer:54602): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:07.814: removable-device-1-connect: missing action removable-device-1-connect

(vmplayer:54602): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:07.814: removable-device-1-nic-bridged: missing action removable-device-1-nic-bridged

(vmplayer:54602): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:07.814: removable-device-1-nic-nat: missing action removable-device-1-nic-nat

(vmplayer:54602): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:07.814: removable-device-1-nic-host-only: missing action removable-device-1-nic-host-only

(vmplayer:54602): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:07.814: removable-device-1-edit: missing action removable-device-1-edit

(vmplayer:54602): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:07.814: removable-device-2connect: missing action removable-device-2connect

(vmplayer:54602): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:07.814: removable-device-2-edit: missing action removable-device-2-edit

(vmplayer:54602): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:07.815: removable-device-0: missing action removable-device-0

(vmplayer:54602): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:07.815: removable-device-1: missing action removable-device-1

(vmplayer:54602): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:07.815: removable-device-2: missing action removable-device-2

(vmplayer:54602): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:07.815: removable-device-0-choose-image: missing action removable-device-0-choose-image

(vmplayer:54602): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:07.815: removable-device-0-edit: missing action removable-device-0-edit

(vmplayer:54602): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:07.815: removable-device-1-connect: missing action removable-device-1-connect

(vmplayer:54602): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:07.815: removable-device-1-nic-bridged: missing action removable-device-1-nic-bridged

(vmplayer:54602): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:07.815: removable-device-1-nic-nat: missing action removable-device-1-nic-nat

(vmplayer:54602): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:07.815: removable-device-1-nic-host-only: missing action removable-device-1-nic-host-only

(vmplayer:54602): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:07.815: removable-device-1-edit: missing action removable-device-1-edit

(vmplayer:54602): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:07.815: removable-device-2connect: missing action removable-device-2connect

(vmplayer:54602): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:07.815: removable-device-2-edit: missing action removable-device-2-edit

Upon searching the net, I found that the error means that intel virtualization is not enabled yet, this is weird because I have make sure the option is checked on BIOS, to make sure it is enabled, I'm following this answer to check for availability of vt.
$ sudo modprobe msr
$ sudo rdmsr 0x3A
20005

I read that value of 3, 5, 7 mean is enabled, what does 20005 mean then ?
kvm-ok tells a different story though.
$ sudo kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used

I'm using debian 12

Have you verified if hardware virtualization is actually enabled within UEFI?

@Ramhound Yes it is enabled

What other hypervisers other than VMWare do you have installed? Your error definitely suggests it’s disabled or not available

You can also use another virtual machine, such as Oracle's free VirtualBox, which runs well without Windows or firmware virtualization.

@Ramhound I tried with virt-manager (kvm) and it works without problem
